# Finding difference in an image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-comparison

I have image as follows:

[image]

I want to detect 5 dials for processing. Hough circles is detecting all other irrelevant circles. to solve this i created a plain image and generated absolute difference with this one. It gave this image:

[image]

I drew box around it and final image is:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
Mat img1 = imread(image_path1, COLOR_BGR2GRAY); 
Mat img2 = imread(image_path2, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

cv::Mat diffImage;
cv::absdiff(img2, img1, diffImage);

cv::Mat foregroundMask = cv::Mat::zeros(diffImage.rows, diffImage.cols, CV_8UC3);

float threshold = 30.0f;
float dist;

for(int j=0; j<diffImage.rows; ++j)
{
    for(int i=0; i<diffImage.cols; ++i)
    {
        cv::Vec3b pix = diffImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i);

        dist = (pix[0]*pix[0] + pix[1]*pix[1] + pix[2]*pix[2]);
        dist = sqrt(dist);

        if(dist>threshold)
        {
            foregroundMask.at<unsigned char>(j,i) = 255;
        }
    }
}

cvtColor(diffImage,diffImage,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

Mat1b img = diffImage.clone();

// Binarize image
Mat1b bin = img > 70;

// Find non-black points
vector<Point> points;
findNonZero(bin, points);

// Get bounding rect
Rect box = boundingRect(points);

// Draw (in color)
rectangle(img1, box, Scalar(0,255,0), 3);

// Show
imshow("Result", img1);
```

Now the issue is i cant compare plain image with anyother iamge of different sizes. Any pointer to right direction will be very helpful.

Regards,
Saghir A. Khatr

**Edit**
My plain image is as follows

[image]

I want to create a standard sample plain image which can  be used with any image to detect that portion...

Comment: basically i have nothing to worry about except 5 dials in image. which i am doing furthur process

Comment: Ok, then try any rigid registration sample code. In the fixed image ,,plaid,, keep numbers and dials. Mask the plates only.

Comment: @mainactual plates means the hands??

Comment: I mean that your registration metric should be calculated inside the white plates only. But not against your plain but hands-only-removed-plain-image.

Comment: At best, you need to perform registration with rotation and scaling. Unless you have a good registration algorithm handy, I'd recommend to customize a generalized Hough procedure so that it detects five touching circles in a row. This should be much more discriminant than the search for single circles.

Comment: Can we see the output of Hough ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust sadly i removed output of houghCircles :( sorry